# How might one swear in Proto-Indo-European?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european

Proto-Indo-European is an interesting topic. I'm fascinated by how it spread. But, I wonder how to use curse words. These words, like others, will probably be reconstructed from other languages: Latin, Ancient Greek, and Sanskrit. I looked up classic curse words, and all I found were words like *shit* giving "to divide", and the *fuck* giving "prick" (the latter is oddly cognate with the Latin word for fist).

Are there reconstructed curse words, and if so, what are they?

Comment: I could also see an on-topic question coming out of this if it were "are there any expletives or interjections reconstructed for Proto-Indo-European?"—comparative stuff tends to be better received.

Comment: you should clarify what kind of curses. It seems you either just mean the emphatic *Oh! Uh!! Yuck!!!* variant or you are to friggin'' stuck up to spell it out, gosh darn it. Anything else would be too broad anyway. Google for Cursing in Luwian, for example, or Merseburger Zaubersprüche -- the horse one is not about heeling, I tell you. What a lame horse had that idea should be put down.

Comment: @NumberFile do everyone a favor and edit the question so it no longer looks like you're trying to figure out how to swear in an actual language, but instead, what is the current state of knowledge in reconstructing PIE curses, swears and interjection, whether we know if they were used as they are in the descendant languages (not all languages have "curses" exactly the same way we mean them), or whether we know of another class of terms that served similar purposes. Also, definitely spell the words you're using in your question in full. If swearing is not allowed, quoting relevant words it.

Comment: Curses are spoken language. Does PIE specify when things are spoken? Most words are actual things.

Comment: Linguistics does not "involve curse words". It analyses languages that have them...

Comment: Closing this question as if it's a translation question and not a reconstruction question is beyond silly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always count on biological functions to furnish vulgarisms:

- fornicate:  *YEBh, EIBh > Greek οιφω, Sanskrit yabhati, Russian ебать
- defecate:  *GhED > Greek χεζω, Sanskrit hadati
- feces: *SKER > Greek σκωρ/σκατ-, Old English scearn

Comment: That is a very smart way to reconstruct these words, they would be cool to go after a time traveling

Comment: What makes you think that these words were tabooized in PIE? Greek οἴφω is definitely not a swear word.

Comment: All anybody knows about PIE comes from studying the daughter IE languages and extrapolating backward.  If these words are "tabooized" in the latter, it's a good bet that they were in PIE.  The precise usage of one Greek word is not the point.  A word from the same old root is a common insult in Russian, and words for fornication are taboo or vulgar in many languages.

Comment: Wouldn't taboo words be _less_ likely to be inherited into daughter languages?

Comment: Vulgarities used as curses aren't really taboo.

Comment: yes, the taboo depends on context. dysphemism is perhaps the word you are looking for. The *euphemism treadmill* would make dysphemisms only stronger; but I'd conjecture there's also a dysphemism cycle, in which dysphemism wear off and loose their edge through usage and become acceptable in formal language--perhaps *gay* for example, though it had a head start as euphemism initially. As I said, depends on context. Vice versa, for the bad euphemisms, you have to wonder whether they started as reinterpretation of something else, eu- or dysphemistic.

Comment: I agree, by the way that significant distribution of cognate course words might allow inference, but two reflexes per etymon are not enough, especially if it's doubtful whether you are sure those are being used in a rude voice or not, and even more so if slurs travel fast. After all, each language swears differently. And bad words are some of the first foreign words I learned on the playground: *suka bled, idi na hui*.

Comment: I wanted to fix the notation so it's something people actually use, but these reconstructions are dodgy. \*EIBh / *\*ei̯bʰ* isn't a properly formed PIE root and schwebeablaut is always questionable; *\*h₃i̯ebʰ-* accounts for all the forms. The second one obviously has to be *\*ǵʰed-*, not *\*gʰed-*. The third one must be *\*sek-*, not *\*sker-*; the ρ in the nominative in Greek is clearly part of the suffix (it's a heteroclitic r/n-stem: the α in the oblique cases goes back to *\*n̥*).

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is not far from sight. Both Greek and Latin use the names of the deities in phrases like τὸν Δία "by Zeus" = *pro iovem* "by Jove" as oaths, and that seems like good indication their remote ancestors did likewise.

Comment: I don't think using two languages that had centuries of a shared cultural and literary output should be taken as indicative of a proto-language spoken 3,000 years prior to their literary activity.

Comment: As with all things derivative of the Neogrammarian method, I would appreciate someone chiming in with information as to whether the pro + deity in accusative construction is of Greek origin. I would assume that they developed independently unless shown thus and also assume that they are valid phrasal/mythological comparanda.